# Test return value from jest mocked event callback

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component in Button.tsx:

```
// Button.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button as ReactstrapButton } from 'reactstrap';

interface IHandlerParams<onClickArgsType> {
  onClickParams?: onClickArgsType
}

export interface IButtonProps<onClickArgsType = {}> {
  color?: string,
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<any>, args?: onClickArgsType) => any,
  handlersParams?: IHandlerParams<onClickArgsType>
}

interface IHandlers {
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<any>
}

export class Button<onClickArgsType> extends React.Component<IButtonProps<onClickArgsType>> {

  private handlers: IHandlers;

  constructor(props: IButtonProps<onClickArgsType>) {
    super(props);
    this.handlers = {
      onClick: (MouseEvent:React.MouseEvent<any>) => { if (this.props.onClick) {this.props.onClick( MouseEvent, this.props.handlersParams ? this.props.handlersParams.onClickParams : undefined) }}
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactstrapButton
        color={this.props.color}
        onClick={this.handlers.onClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ReactstrapButton>
    )
  }
}
```

***NOTE:*** I am using that weird "handlers" object to manage the event's callback, so that I do not have an arrow function directly in the ReactstrapButton properties, avoiding creating a new object each time and thus preventing the component from being re-rendered.

And a corresponding test file in Button.unit.test.tsx:

```
// Button.unit.test.tsx
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import * as React from "react";

import { Button, IButtonProps } from "./Button";

interface IOnClickParamsTest {
  a: number,
  b: number
}

describe('App component', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(
      <Button />
    );
  });

  it('test the onClick method', () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn((event: React.MouseEvent<IButtonProps<IOnClickParamsTest>>, params: IOnClickParamsTest) => params.a + params.b);
    const onClickParams: IOnClickParamsTest = { a: 4, b: 5 };

    const buttonComponent = mount(
      <Button<IOnClickParamsTest>
        onClick={onClick}
        handlersParams={{ onClickParams }}
      />
    );
    buttonComponent.simulate("click");

    expect(onClick).toBeCalled();
    expect(onClick.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe(onClickParams);// The second argument of the first call to the function was onClickParams
    // expect(onClick.mock.results[0].value).toBe(9);// The return value of the first call to the function was 9
  });

});
```

The test passes as expected, but fails in the last commented line with following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

The error is referencing to the onClick.mock.results property. I have debugged the onClick.mock property and results, of course, is not there. Nevertheless, as per [this docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function) in Jest, there should exist a results property in there.

By the way, I am using :

```
"react": "^16.4.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.0",

"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
"jest": "^23.1.0",
"jest-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
"ts-jest": "^22.4.6"
```

Any thoughts? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Interesting, results was added in Jest 23.0.0, are you sure you're running 23.0+?  I don't think create-react-app uses the latest yet, if you bootstrapped with create-react-app and are using react-scripts-ts you can check with "npm test -- --version"

Comment: Good catch @brian-lives-outdoors, I run npm test -- --version and I found that my react-scripts-ts is using Jest version 22.4.2.
Do you know what could be the best approach to upgrade jest and ts-jest (current version 22.0.1)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to eject from create-react-app to upgrade Jest, and that is not recommended.  create-react-app will update to v23 at some point.  In the meantime, you can test the return value now using [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/).  I created an answer to capture this info, let me know if this covers what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is available in Jest v23.  Apps bootstrapped using create-react-app with react-scripts-ts as of today (Aug 1, 2018) are using Jest v22.  create-react-app will be updated to use Jest v23 in the near future.

In the meantime, testing the return value is possible using [Sinon fakes](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.4/fakes/).

In this case the updated test looks like this:

```
// Button.unit.test.tsx
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import * as React from "react";
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

import { Button, IButtonProps } from "./Button";

interface IOnClickParamsTest {
  a: number,
  b: number
}

describe('App component', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(
      <Button />
    );
  });

  it('test the onClick method', () => {
    const onClick = sinon.fake((event: React.MouseEvent<IButtonProps<IOnClickParamsTest>>, params: IOnClickParamsTest) => params.a + params.b);
    const onClickParams: IOnClickParamsTest = { a: 4, b: 5 };

    const buttonComponent = mount(
      <Button<IOnClickParamsTest>
        onClick={onClick}
        handlersParams={{ onClickParams }}
      />
    );
    buttonComponent.simulate("click");

    expect(onClick.calledOnce).toBe(true);
    expect(onClick.firstCall.args[1]).toBe(onClickParams);
    expect(onClick.returnValues[0]).toBe(9);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @brian-lives-outdoors ! It was a helpful answer!